# Running spatstat functions on GPU

Tags: spatstat

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193482/is-it-possible-to-run-spatstat-functions-on-multiple-processors), I learned how to run the spatstat functions on multiprocessors, I was wondering whether we can run spatstat functions on GPU. If yes, I am very thankful if you mention how we can run the following code on GPU.

Best regards

```
library(spatstat)
ppplist <- replicate(4, cells, simplify = FALSE)
envlist <- parallel::mclapply(ppplist, spatstat::envelope, savefuns = TRUE, nsim = 10)
envfinal <- do.call(pool, envlist)
envfinal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether `spatstat` makes use of GPU hardware at a low level (in its internal C code), the answer is no. The internal C code is designed to be portable across a wide range of systems, rather than exploiting special hardware.

It may be possible to install R with support for GPU hardware. That would have an effect on the performance of `spatstat` because it would accelerate the base R functionality such as sorting, on which `spatstat` relies heavily.

Using GPU's does not necessarily make things run faster - it depends on the task and on the code - but we imagine that the `spatstat` simulation engine `rmh` could be made to run faster with GPU's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I was wondering whether it is possible that you show how we can run the above code (or any other small code that you think would be useful) on GPU?

Comment: I would be very thankful if someone can help me with the question mentioned in this thread.